# Google Dataflow: running dynamic query with BigQuery+Pub/Sub in Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

**What I would like to do in the pipeline:**

1. Read from pub/sub (done)
2. Transform this data to dictionary (done)
3. Take the value of a specified key from the dict (done)
4. Run a parametrized/dynamic query from BigQuery in which the where part should be like this:

   ```
   SELECT field1 FROM Table where field2 = @valueFromP/S
   ```

---

**The pipeline**

```
| 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription='')
| 'String to dictionary' >> beam.Map(lambda s:data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
| 'BigQuery' >> <Here is where I'm not sure how to do it>
```

The normal way to read from BQ it would be like:

```
| 'Read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
                query="SELECT field1 FROM table where field2='string'", use_standard_sql=True))
```

---

I have read about parameterized [queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries#bigquery-query-params-python) but i'm not sure if this would work with apache beam.

It could be done using side inputs?

Which would be the best way to do this?

---

What I've tried:

```
def parse_methodBQ(input):
    query=''SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE field1=\'%s\' AND field2=True' % (input['field1'])'
    return query


class ReadFromBigQuery(beam.PTransform):
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
                pcoll
                | 'FormatQuery' >> beam.Map(parse_methodBQ)
                | 'Read' >> beam.Map(lambda s:  beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=s)))
        )

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
transform = (p  | 'BQ' >> ReadFromBigQuery()
```

The result (why this?):

```
<Read(PTransform) label=[Read]>
```

The correct result should be like:

```
{u'Field1': u'string', u'Field2': Bool}
```

---

**THE SOLUTION**

In the pipeline:

```
| 'BQ' >> beam.Map(parse_method_BQ))
```

The function (using the BigQuery 0.25 API for dataflow)

```
def parse_method_BQ(input):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    QUERY = 'SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE field1=\'%s\' AND field2=True' % (input['field1'])
    client.use_legacy_sql = False
    query_job = client.run_async_query(query=QUERY ,job_name='temp-query-job_{}'.format(uuid.uuid4()))  # API request
    query_job.begin()
    while True:
        query_job.reload()  # Refreshes the state via a GET request.
        if query_job.state == 'DONE':
            if query_job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(query_job.errors)
            rows = query_job.results().fetch_data()
            for row in rows:
                if not (row[0] is None):  
                    return input
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [read the whole table](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#reading-from-a-table) or use a [string query](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#reading-with-a-query-string).

I understand that you will use the parse_methodBQ method to customize the query as needed. As this method returns a query, you can call it with BigQuerySource. The rows are  in dictionary.

```
| 'QueryTable' >> beam.Map(beam.io.BigQuerySource(parse_methodBQ))
# Each row is a dictionary where the keys are the BigQuery columns
| 'Read' >> beam.Map(lambda s:  s['data'])
```

Further more, you can avoid having to customize the query and use a [filter method](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/6d8fa455d4b478335167235f56620744d9e22784/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/filters.py#L36)

Regarding the side inputs, review [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/bigquery_side_input.py) example from the cookbook to have a better view on how to use them.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I did it using beam.Map so it should be like the solution you propose. I will add the solution to the main post.

Comment: Which would be better for max performance: using [filter data](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/6d8fa455d4b478335167235f56620744d9e22784/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/filters.py#L36) or using a parse_method like I did?

Comment: Depending on your use case, if you will you are using multiple custom queries it may be better to have all the table an use a filter but if you are only doing a few custom queries having all the table may be useless.